# why a is 2130567168 for a in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
    public:
    int a;

};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    X x;
    std::cout<<x.a<<std::endl;

  }
```

why is 2130567168?  not 0?

Comment: "Luck" - because if it was 0 here, you might have relied upon it!

Comment: Well, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I'm guessing the OP had some experience with Java, where integer _fields_ are initialized to 0, in which case, a good answer might be "because C++ is different from Java" #justsayin

Answer (score 8):

It could be anything. Since `x.a` is uninitialized it's value is **Indeterminate**.
In C++, class members are not default initialized. They need explicit initialization, in the absence of any they remain uninitialized. 
Using any such uninitialized class members gives your program only one thing, **Undefined Behavior**.

You need to initialize `x.a` to something meaningful, using the **[Member Initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**.

```
class X 
{
    public:
        int a;
         X(int i):a(i){}
         X():a(0){}
};
```